# Ни в какую не хочет запрос записывать в бд строку, содержащую одинарную кавычку?

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим нужно записать в БД строку:

> it's my life

код:

```
$post = trim($_POST['data']);
$record = htmlspecialchars($post);

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mytable`(`field`) VALUES ('$record')");

if (!$query)
{

    echo "bad query";
}
else 
{

    echo "data added!";

}
```

В общем без апострофа в тексте **it's my life** запись добавится в базу, а с ним нет, как это обойти?

п.с. использую строго **mysql**, никаких **PDO** и **MySQLi**.

Comment: А ПОЧЕМУ НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТЕ PDO? на мой взгляд намного лучше работать

Comment: вопрос не стоит PDO не PDO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$record = mysql_real_escape_string($record);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mytable`(`field`) VALUES ('$record')");
```

Comment: а я mysql_escape_string смотрел на php.net, а оно там deprecated просто и испугался.

Answer (score 0):

Такие символы нужно экранировать(перекрывать спереди косой чертой) вместо кавычки должно быть " \' ". Также и с двойной кавычкой " \" ".
[Подробней почитать можно здесь.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)  Таблица 9.1. список всех символов которые нужно экранировать.